# Requisitar prop baseado em outra prop

Tags: vue.js

Olá, eu tenho um componente que deve receber duas props, uma que indica se este componente precisa de uma data e uma data que deve ser passada se e somente se o componente precisar de uma data. Desse modo, o componente deve jogar uma exception caso a prop needsDate seja passada como true e nenhuma data for passada. pensei no seguinte código:

```
props: {
  needsDate: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  date: {
    type: String,
    required: this.needsDate
  }
}
```

O problema é que esta forma não gera o comportamento esperado, quando passo needsDate=true sem passar date o componente renderiza date como undefined ao invés de dar throw num erro. Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender por que isso acontece e/ou qual a maneira correta de fazer isto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há um [issue no Github com exatamente esta dúvida](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3495#issuecomment-241430642). O que é sugerido lá por um dos membros da equipa do Vue é fazer essa verificação dentro do `created` que é chamado antes do componente ser montado no DOM.

De inicio pensei que o [`validator`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation) poderia ajudar aqui, mas nessa função que possibilita fazer uma verificação customizada a uma `prop` não é possível aceder à instância porque ainda não foi criada nem a outras propriedades.